# Multivariable Calculus Question - Calculating the area of a filter with two cylindrical ducts

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The problem states that there are two cylindrical ducts, one duct with radius 5m and the other duct with radius 1m. The cylindrical duct with the radius of 5m is on the positive y-axis and the duct with radius 1m is on the positive z-axis. Where the two ducts meet, there is a screen to filter out dust and junk. Junk can be in the duct with radius 5m but not in the duct with radius 1m.

The question wants you to setup up a calculus problem that will help you learn the precise area of the screen.

I'm not sure how to begin this problem and am in need of some guidance on the problem.

Here is a picture of the problem:

[Picture of what is going on with the cylindrical ducts and the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mZ2k.jpg)

Comment: I initially imagined the screen to be just a 1m radius circle. But based on the context of the problem, I'm now imagining it's the shape you'd get if you shone a 1m circle of light onto the 5m cylinder and cut out the resulting shape. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm guessing the setup is supposed to look like this picture.

Here, the big cylinder is shown in a circular cross section; the y axis is pointed toward the viewer. The small cylinder is shown in rectangular cross section; the z-axis goes from left to right. And the x axis goes from top to bottom.

If I understand you correctly, the screen will be the red region shown here. If that's true, then we can get its area by computing the length of that curve and then revolving it about the z-axis to make it a three-dimensional shape instead of a two-dimensional curve.

The first bit of calculus (or maybe geometry) will give you the length of that curve, and the second bit of calculus (or maybe geometry) will give you the corresponding area of the surface of revolution.

Comment: Hey, I added a picture of what is going on with the cylindrical ducts and the screen. Hopefully it helps